# Pes 2013 on ubuntu

Tags: wine

I"m new to ubuntu and I don't know how to install pes2013.
 I've already downloaded wine to run .exe but the installer wizard says :"your system hasn't been modified"

how can I install it ??

Comment: Have you installed Wine?  If so how?

Answer (score 1):

It should run, you can find out details here about what version etc...
http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=26766

Apparently there are no special requirements.

Once you have the correct version of wine, you can run it from the terminal using wine

Comment: the installer runs okay.

but the wizard shows the error after typing the serial number and and clicking install !!

Comment: @PêTḝrGèRgés Consider using playonlinux for managing different versions of wine. This makes everything a lot easyer as you can easily test the game with different versions of wine.

Comment: This is good advice, I use Play On Linux all the time.  I've gotten some games running that would not otherwise run.

It can even automatically install and manage the correct version of WINE for you for some games though PES isn't on the list in POL for me.